# How can I tell if my building plumbing provides an adequate ground?

Tags: ground, grounding, testing, test-equipment

I work in an old building with two-wire wiring, i.e. no separate ground. Is there some minimum-equipment-purchase way to tell if a wire soldered to a building plumbing pipe is an adequate ground? I have a standard hand-held multi-meter.

Comment: You shouldn't even need to solder, just use one of [these](http://www.homedepot.com/catalog/productImages/1000/50/5055d3fd-3a1a-4b9e-ad22-e779a323e9a2_1000.jpg).

Comment: This can be dangerous, and I believe it is illegal in the United States.

Comment: http://www.finehomebuilding.com/2005/05/01/can-i-ground-an-outlet-to-a-metal-water-pipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://homeguides.sfgate.com/plumbing-system-electrical-grounding-94939.html

This author above suggests plumbing can supplement and earth ground rod, but not be a primary connection.

Building codes in your area determine the ultimate answer.

Ask relevant city authorities for reference to building codes for commercial ground methods or consult an electrician.

Certainly deep water lines are better than no ground for equipment that needs to protect you from stray leakage from dust and humidity on metal shell electrical tools.

I might measure the AC voltage from the plumbing to Neutral and see how much voltage drop there is.  ( must be < 5% line) ) ... this is grounded outside at the transformer but current can cause a voltage drop.

Answer (score 1):

Adequate is a bit of a vague descriptor but I'll assume that you are trying to make a GFIC work. You don't even need a multi-meter - a voltage/continuity tester will do. Meter from Neutral to ground (the box). If you have continuity there, meter from hot to ground (still the box) and see if you get 120v. If you have good voltage and continuity to ground on the neutral the GFIC will hold.

You should/can also check your main water line to ensure that there is a jumper wire in place around any water meter. You may have good ground without the jumper but it isn't a sure thing.

Hope that helps.

Chris

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your response. It's not for a GFIC, just looking to anchor some electronic equipment.  Question: How is there continuity between the neutral and the pipe? Is the circuit made through the literal ground, the earth under the building?

Comment: Hey Andrew, this is a code issue in general but the short answer is that if you have EMT/IMC in the walls there is a bonding bar in the panel which connects the box to the neutral. This creates the continuity for the building/water-main ground.  If you want to back that up with a distinct ground wire the clamp @thePhoton suggested is the way to go, provided it's a cold water pipe AND there is a jumper on the water meter.

Answer (score 0):

You first have to check whether the plumbing has sufficient earth connection at all. That one doesn't depend on the age of the building because your water supplier may have decided to replace the plumbing **outside** the building by plastic tubes. Tools you need: documentation.

When in doubt, you have to install proper earthing outside the building yourself.

Comment: As long as there's a few feet of metal pipe buried in the earth, it shouldn't matter much whether the upstream supply pipes are metal or plastic.

Comment: Things to watch out for would be PEX pipe spliced into the building's plumbing, and dielectric joins used to connect copper and iron sections of the plumbing.

Comment: @Janka The problem is, I don't own the building. I don't even have access to the basement.